# How to center text using fluidRow and mainPanel?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to center some text in a `fluidRow` in a `mainPanel`. Hence, I tried:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    fluidRow(
      align = "center",
      "How to center this?"
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, the text is clearly off the center (too far left). If I omit the `mainPanel(...)` it works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is indeed centered, the `mainPanel` just does not take full width.
If you look at `?mainPanel()`, the parameter of `width` is 8 by default. If you want full width set it to 12.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
   mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
         align = "center",
         "How to center this?"
      ), width = 12
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```